# How do not let the game close itself

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

This game's behaviour is absolutely unpredictable. Sometimes you can do stuff in another apps for a long time, then return to TDS and find it still ruinning, and sometimes you only minimize TDS, and it closes. Has anyone there found out which is the optimal way of dealing with this so you can open other apps and won't have to wait for the app to open all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the app is closing itself, it's that the operating system is closing the app because it needs the resources for the other apps you're running. The only "optimal" way is to not run any other apps, and even then you're not guaranteed that it won't get closed.

Comment: This is so true. With iOS 7 I can't keep more than one app active at a time on my iPad 2.  I guess I'll have to upgrade just to deal with the OS. :(